# Heron's method JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The following code is supposed to return the square root using Heron's method. I am trying to find a "bug" in it, but to be honest, I haven't been able to spot it. I have a question about the "var prevGuess = n" statement. How does "n" work the first time? Is that the bug, and what's the "fix?"

Thanks, I am a bit confused at the moment......

```
function heronSqrt(n)
{
    var DELTA = 1.0E-10;
    var nextGuess;
    var prevGuess = n;
    do
    {
        nextGuess = (prevGuess + (n/prevGuess))/2;
        prevGuess = nextGuess;
    } while (nextGuess-prevGuess > DELTA)
    return nextGuess;
}
```

Comment: `n` is passed as a parameter to the function

Comment: Why are you trying to find a bug? Is it not giving the correct result?

Comment: @DominicBarnes this might be a homework, and he needs to find if there is anything wrong with it.

Comment: `heronSqrt(25)` is giving me `13`.

Comment: Under what conditions should the loop exit? What are the values of `nextGuess` and `prevGuess`, and when do they get set?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working version:

```
function heronSqrt(n)
{
    var DELTA = 1.0E-10;
    var nextGuess  = n;
    var prevGuess;
    do
    {
        prevGuess = nextGuess;
        nextGuess = (prevGuess + (n/prevGuess))/2;
    } while (Math.abs(nextGuess-prevGuess) > DELTA)
    return nextGuess;
}
```

There were two problems. First, you  were updating "prevGuess" *before* doing the limit check.  Second, you need to check the absolute value of the difference between the guesses. I altered the initialization so that it's "nextGuess" that's initialized to the input value, moved the update to "prevGuess" to the first line of the loop, and I added the call to `Math.abs()`.

To make this work for a greater range of values, I *think* you need to have the value of "DELTA" be proportional to the magnitude of "n".  If you try this with huge numbers, it probably won't converge.